# Chi-squared and sample variance

Tags: self-study, variance, sample, chi-squared-distribution

> Each member of a random sample of 20 business economists was asked to predict the rate of inflation for the coming year.  Assume that the predictions for the whole population of business economists follow a normal distribution with standard deviation 2%.
>
> a. The probability is 0.01 that the sample standard deviation is bigger than what number?
>
> b. The probability is 0.025 that the sample standard deviation is smaller than what number?
>
> c. Find any pair of numbers such that the probability that the sample standard deviation lies between these numbers is 0.90.

Having a lot of difficulty with chi-squared problems mostly because I do not know how to manipulate the chi-squared distribution. Here is my answer for a):

a) $P(K>s^2)=0.01$, $P(\chi^2 > \frac{19s^2}{4})=0.01$

From the chi-squared table:

$P(\chi^2 > 36.19)=0.01$, then $\frac{19s^2}{4}=36.19$, $s^2=7.619$

How do we solve when it's "smaller than" or "between"? Is there a way to manipulate the equations, the same way as for normal distributions?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think such calculations would be any different for the $\chi^2$ distribution than for the Normal distribution?

Comment: I mean: $P(z>z')=1-P(z<z')$, $P(z<z')=area.from.table$, $P(z'<z<z'')=P(z<z'')-P(z<z')$

Comment: The chi-squared distribution doesn't work that way does it?

Comment: Thank you! Just did it. Would appreciate if someone would help me solve b) and c). Just guidelines at least.

Comment: All continuous distributions work that way.  This amounts to the definition of a distribution function.  In fact, *all* distributions work this way provided you are careful about where to put strict inequalities "$\lt$" and inequalities "$\le$". For instance, $$\Pr(z \gt z^\prime) = 1 - \Pr(z \le z^\prime).$$

Comment: In normal distributions $\ge$ or $>$ doesn't change anything. So you're talking about chi-squared distribution?